# Playable area in Spritekit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, universal

I am making a landscape universal game with Spritekit and Swift in Xcode 6.1. I have been researching about how to make a universal app, and there seems to be a lot to do in regards to layout so that your game looks the same across all devices.

I have read that you can do this by defining a "playable area" in which you put all your game features into. The link below shows a image explaining the playable area idea.

http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Aspect-Ratio-Diff.jpg

Apart from the 1 tutorial I have found online talking about this, (which wasn't for Swift) I cannot find anything about how to actually "define" a playable area for Swift in Spritekit.

Is there a way I can create a rectangle, lets say on the iPhone 6 for example, so that it will cover all devices as long as I build my game within that rectangle?

Basically how do I define a "playable area" so that I can see the boundaries that I have to build my app within? Like in the linked picture?

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the layout appear the same on every device , assuming u support iPhone 5 and above only . You can make use of .Aspectfill under your GameViewController to scale the scene to fit all the resolutions. This means that you will be using the iOS 5 simulator and that you will relinquish support of iPhone 4s.

The best way to define a playable area would be to either create a rectangle node that encompasses a certain area while ensuring that your physics world is showing physics for testing.

If you want to build for each screen size natively, you would have to adjust your content manually as technically , devices such as the iPhone 6 plus for example are designed so you can see more things.

Comment: Thanks. I created the rectangle. :D

Comment: if you found this question helpful, mark a tick so that the question is marked as solved so others who see this question and have the same problem will have an easier time.